# how to connect proxies in the ccxt library?

Tags: proxy, ccxt

I try to call a function (sell/buy, whatever) through a proxy, but it gives an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
account_binance = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': API_KEY,
    'secret': API_SECRET,
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'options': {
        'defaultType': 'spot'
    },
    'proxy': f'http://{login}:{password}@{ip}:3000'
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a new key `proxies` to the input where you can set your proxy information in both `http` and `https` modes. The correct format is `'host_name_or_ip:port_number'`. Here is an example where I used v2ray proxy:

```
api_binance = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': API_KEY,
    'secret': API_SECRET,
    'proxies': {
        'http': '127.0.0.1:10809',
        'https': '127.0.0.1:10809',
    }
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Proxies are unified in CCXT. You can set instance properties:

- `.proxyUrl`
- `.httpProxy`
- `.httpsProxy`
- `.socksProxy`

read more at: https://docs.ccxt.com/#/?id=proxy